# Suppose you drove from $A$ to $B$ at $30 \text{ mph}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose you drive from $A$ to $B$ at $30$ mph. How fast must you drive on the return trip so that your average speed for the round trip is $60$ mph?

My work so far:

Trip A-->B: $(30 \text{ mph})(1 \text{ hr})=30 \text{ mi}$

Return trip B-->A: $(v \text{ mph})(\frac{30}v \text{ hr})=30 \text{ mi}$

Round trip: $(60 \text{ mph})(1+\frac{30}v \text{ hr})=60 \text{ mi}$

Is this the correct set-up? If so, can I solve for the $v$ which represents the speed in the return trip?

Answer (score 2):

Let $d$ be the distance between $A$ & $B$ and $v$ be the speed on return trip be then we have

1. Time $t_1$ taken to reach from $A\to B$ $$t_1=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}=\frac{d}{30}$$
2. Time $t_2$ taken to reach from $B\to A$ $$t_2=\frac{\text{distance}}{\text{speed}}=\frac{d}{v}$$

Hence, total time spent on the round trip $$t_1+t_2=\frac{d}{30}+\frac{d}{v}$$
Hence, the average speed for the round trip $$=\frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time spent}}$$ $$\frac{2d}{\frac{d}{30}+\frac{d}{v}}=60$$
$$\frac{1}{v}+\frac{1}{30}=\frac{2}{60}$$
$$\frac{1}{v}=\frac{2}{60}-\frac{1}{30}=0$$
$$v\to \infty$$ this value of the speed practically is impossible, hence there is no solution

Answer (score 0):

**It is not possible.** Proof:

$$\overline{v} = \frac{\sum \Delta x}{\sum \Delta t} = \frac{\sum \Delta x}{\sum \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta v}}$$

Now you want the round-trip $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow A$. As it is a round-trip we may suppose that $A \rightarrow B$ and $B \rightarrow A$ are of equal length, so you can set $A=\frac{1}{2}$ as well as $B=\frac{1}{2}$. But then we have

$$\overline{v} = \frac{0.5+0.5}{\frac{0.5}{30} + \frac{0.5}{v_2}} \overset{!}{=} 60$$

where $v_2$ is the velocity on the return trip $B \to A$. This evolves to

$$1 = 1 + \frac{30}{v_2} \iff 0 = \frac{30}{v_2}$$

But this means that $v_2 \to \infty$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

let distance between A and B be $s$, and you travel with speed $v_1=30$ for time $t_1=\frac{s}{v_1}$ now you return with speed $v_2$ for time $t_2=\frac{s}{v_2}$ , awerage speed is (total distance traveled divided bu travel time)$$ v_{avg}=\frac{s+s}{t_1+t_2}=\frac{2s}{\frac{s}{v_1}+\frac{s}{v_2}}=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{v_1}+\frac{1}{v_2}}$$ you said that $v_{avg}=60=2v_1$
so
$$2v_1(\frac{1}{v_1}+\frac{1}{v_2})=2$$
$$ 2+\frac{v_1}{v_2}=2$$
$$ \frac{v_1}{v_2}=0$$
meaning there is no solution (unless your $v_2$ is infinite and you watch it as limit)

Answer (score 0):

Let's express it in words. Assume that the distance is $n$ miles. Then the first leg of the trip consumes exactly $\frac{n}{30}$ hours. The return leg would consume another $\frac{n}{30}$ hours at $\frac{30m}{h}$ , but the speed must suddenly be increased to the point where the average speed for the entire round trip will come to $\frac{60m}{h}$ . This cannot be done, because the $\frac{n}{30}$ hours which would be required for the entire round trip at $\frac{60m}{h}$ has already been consumed by the first leg at $\frac{30m}{h}$ .